# Center of clusteres in rapidminer

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, rapidminer

I have six features that are clustered using k-means algorithm in Rapidminer, I want detect outlier data from these. there is  centroid table in Rapidminer that show the center of each feature in each cluster. I want to detect  outlier using cluster method(k-means) so i have avg within centroid distance-cluster but i want to calculate distance between each data from center of cluster. I don't know how to calculate a center point for each cluster with 6 features in rapidminer? and i have 6 feature for each data how calculate a point for each data and calculate distance of each data to center of cluster in rapidminer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Cross Distances` operator for this. This calculates the distances between all pairs of examples in two example sets. Use the `Extract Cluster Prototype` operator to find the cluster centroids and connect the output of this to one of the inputs of the `Cross Distances` operator. The original example set is connected to the other input. You can change the distance measure in this operator used but the default is Euclidean distance.